# Working in betting company vs working in loan company

Tags: halal-haram, work

I am a developer and ever since I moved to Europe I worked in Loan providing company. My work include designing the website and things related to getting a loan e.g filling online form etc. Lately, I been getting a lot of calls from Gambling industry, the job is similar but what if I will be making online digital version of poker or slot machines. what I know to best of my knowledge that Gambling is haram, so my question is.

Is the money haram when it comes to me, My reason for saying no is that the money that I will be paid from gambling (I might be wrong), It can be money from gambling addiction of someone else hard-earned money.

But that raises another issue that the work I am doing in finance industry making forms for someone to apply loans for APR. how does that different to what gambling industry.

Is it wrong me to work in these industries or I am earning from halal means i.e. working hard and thinking too much?

Comment: Well the point is how deep are you involved in riba in the loan company and how deep in gambling. Both jobs are not what a Muslim would be recommended to do for living (but could nevertheless be halal). But as far as I understand you are doing web design or programming which you basically could do for any other company. A X vs Y question however is off-topic here. If you want a recommendation don't quit your job for another job that is not perfectly halal and above any suspicion.

Comment: Generally the question is about if the source of income is unknown e.g some interest which I do not know they earn money to pay but they do loans n there is interest on it but I only make website beautiful and engaging, will my income be halal as I m not directly linked to interest and do my job

Comment: there's already an answer for this question. Just check [tag:riba].

Answer (score -2):

Are these loans interest based? If yes, your work is haram. You need to find something halal. Helping others in wrongdoing is disallowed in Islam.

the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) cursed the one who consumes riba, the one who pays it, **the one who writes it down** and the two who witness it, and he said: they are all the same. Narrated by Muslim in his Saheeh.

Comment: Such claims require evidences supporting them. There's nothing wrong if he is not involved directly in riba transactions by default.